# .NET 6 error: No overload for 'Where' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, where-clause

The code below did work in .NET Framework 4.6 but it won't work in .NET 6 - why? How do I fix it? On the return line, the compiler is showing error:

> No overload for method 'Where' takes 2 arguments

In my database every table inherits from the `ProgramObjects` table.  `ProgramObjects` has a status enumeration column of either Active (1) or Inactive (2) for every record. I use inheritance so I don't need an `IsActive` column in every table in my database. This method is intended to return all inactive records from any table.

```
private IList<T> GetInactiveRecords<T>()
{
     return ProgramObjects.OfType<T>()
                          .Where("StatusEnumeration = @0", StatusEnum.Inactive)
                          .ToList();
}
```

I've researched documentation on the Microsoft website but I'm having trouble understanding how to fix it. And because my code is using generics it's a little more complicated to perform the `Where` filter.  I also tried using string interpolation instead but I didn't have success with that either.

Comment: That's invalid syntax. `Where` is already generic, accepts a *generic* `Func<T,bool>` or `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, never string formulas. Nothing in the docs or sites suggests otherwise. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that code ever to have compiled, at least with normal LINQ. Can you identify which `Where` method it was calling before?

Comment: `The code below did work in .NET Framework 4.6` no it didn't. Were you using some third-party library perhaps, to *dynamically* parse strings into expressions?

Comment: I suspect you were probably using [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamic-linq.net/) before. You may need to upgrade the version you're using to one which supports .NET 6? Look for build/restore errors in your log.

Comment: Were you perhaps using [Dynamic LINQ](https://dynamic-linq.net/)? If you could post a [mcve] (including the project file) that builds on .NET 4.6 but not on .NET 6, that would help...

Comment: Are you using EF Core? In that case you don't need Dynamic LINQ in the first place. You can use `FromSqlXYZ` to use a SQL query as a starting point.  The "Dynamic LINQ" library sacrifices LINQ's main benefit, type safety. If you want to generate queries at runtime, consider just appending `Where` calls based on conditions, or using LINQKit's PredicateBuilder. Your current example is pretty hard-coded by the way, and easy to replace with `if (inactiveOnly) { query=query.Where(t=>t.Inactive);}`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, I was missing the `System.Linq.Dynamic` NuGet package.

Comment: Please don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).